# Fail cross build rust on mac

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

i try to cross build a x86 binary on mac, i run blow command

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
brew tap SergioBenitez/osxct
brew install x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
CARGO_TARGET_X86_64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_LINKER=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc \
cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --bin main
```

and add

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc"
```

at `.cargo/config.toml`
but it still show

```
  error occurred: Command "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-gdwarf-4" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/include" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/src" "-I" "wasm/wasm-sysroot" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DSECP256K1_API=" "-DENABLE_MODULE_ECDH=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_SCHNORRSIG=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_EXTRAKEYS=1" "-DECMULT_GEN_PREC_BITS=4" "-DECMULT_WINDOW_SIZE=15" "-DUSE_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT_CALLBACKS=1" "-o" "/Users/xy/work/freefrom/nostr_spam/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/build/secp256k1-sys-e469179b1d2bac57/out/depend/secp256k1/contrib/lax_der_parsing.o" "-c" "depend/secp256k1/contrib/lax_der_parsing.c" with args "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc" failed to start: Os { code: 86, kind: Uncategorized, message: "Bad CPU type in executable" }
```

Comment: It seems you have attempted run Intel binary on Arm chip or vice versa...?